# Conditional tags to differentiate between profiles and activity with buddypress

Tags: buddypress, conditional-tags

I can't get any help on the buddypress forums so I'm going to ask it here. I'm trying to use conditional tags so I can have a different sidebar for the profile page than the activity page. For some reason the way I have it setup in my sidebar.php still returns the default. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
 if (is_single()){
  include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-single.php');}
 elseif (is_page()){
  include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-index.php');}
 elseif (is_category('fame-game')){
  include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-fame-game.php');}
 elseif (bp_is_user_profile()){
  include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-act.php');}
 else {
  include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-index.php');}
?>
```

Link to buddypress conditional statements codex http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/conditional-template-tags/

SOLVED! See answer with comments below given by Boone Gorges. Here is the resolved code.

```
<?php
 if (is_single()){
 include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-single.php');}
 elseif (is_page() && !bp_is_profile_component()){
 include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-index.php');}
 elseif (is_category('fame-game')){
 include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-fame-game.php');}
 elseif (bp_is_profile_component()) {
 include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-act.php');}
 else {
 include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/sidebar-index.php');}
?>
```

Comment: When and where're you adding this code?

Comment: Oh sorry this is the code in my sidebar.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be the choice of `bp_is_user_profile()`. This only returns true when you are literally looking at the xprofile component - the 'Profile' tab of a user's page. `bp_is_user()` is more general, returning true whenever you're viewing a user page (even if it's user activity, user groups, etc).

[EDIT]

After further discussion with the OP, it looks as if the culprit is `is_page()`. Since BP 1.5, BuddyPress uses WP Pages to display content. That means that the `is_page()` case was returning true. To exclude BP content from this condition, amend your check as follows:

`is_page() && !bp_is_blog_page()`

Alternatively, if you want the `is_page()` content to show on BP content too, *except for user pages*,

`is_page() && !bp_is_user()`

or, to limit it to the profile,

`is_page() && !bp_is_profile_component()`

Comment: I changed it to bp_is_user() and it still returns the last default option for the sidebar.

Comment: What's the URL for the page you're testing? Does it look like this: `http://example.com/members/boonebgorges/`?

Comment: I was using `define ( 'BP_ENABLE_ROOT_PROFILES', true );` to have top level profiles. I changed it back to check but still no dice. So yes it still doesnt work with that permalink structure.

Comment: Strange. You could try `bp_displayed_user_id()` (which will return an int on a user page and 0 otherwise), but I doubt that will work either, since `bp_is_user()` is more or less a wrapper for `bp_displayed_user_id()`. I don't quite understand how user content could be displaying on the rest of the page if these functions return false/0. Are you working with a custom theme, or a child theme of bp-default, or what? Are you loading sidebar.php in a non-standard way?

Comment: Im using a child theme of bp-default. I use `get_sidebar()` to call the sidebar on template pages. I don't get it =(

Comment: Just dawned on me :) is_page() will return true on BP content, because BP (since 1.5) uses WP pages as its basis for display. Try changing your first elseif condition to: `elseif ( is_page() && bp_is_blog_page() )`

Comment: Erg, make that `!bp_is_blog_page()`

Comment: Boom! I needed to have a different sidebar for just the profile pages so I changed `bp_is_blog_page()` to `bp_is_profile_component()` and that used that statement for the third else if and it returned the sidebar-act while leaving the activity page with sidebar-index. Great eye! and thanks for sticking with me! I edited the answer above.

Comment: @PolluxKhafra Don’t edit other peoples answers unless they are really broken. Update your question instead. I had to reject your edit.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the updated info.

Answer (score 0):

#### Read the comments

...for further explanation also read about [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template).

```
<?php
// Build $sidebars array in order of PRIORITY. First things first » overrides later
if ( is_single() )
{
    $sidebars[] = 'single';
}
// Not needed as it's the default one
// elseif ( is_page() )
// {
//     $sidebars[] = 'index';
// }
elseif ( is_category('fame-game') )
{
    $sidebars[] = 'fame-game';
}
elseif ( bp_is_user_profile() )
{
    $sidebars[] = 'act';
}
$sidebars[] = 'index';

// Build names:
foreach ( $sidebars as $index => $name )
    $sidebars[ $index ] = "sidebar-{$name}.php";

// Load & require_once the sidebar
locate_template( $sidebars, true );
?>
```